# How to note tangent to the power -1 in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate direction of mousemove in angles. I found formula but i dont know how to note it:

theta = tan^–1(y/x)

Can you help me? I used this page for solution https://www.dummies.com/education/science/physics/how-to-find-a-vectors-magnitude-and-direction/

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean arc tangent? There is a function called atan() for that, which gives you your angle in radians.

vat theta = Math.atan(y/x)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. It is hard if you dont know math enough and you dont even know what to search for.